# How to increase constant space between li inline-block list elemets?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

The inline-block list items have constant spaces between them by default if the margin is same for all directions. My question is, how can we increase this space BETWEEN list items if we have to using CSS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With an horizontal padding? `padding-left:5px` , `padding-right:5px;`

Or you can use relative positioning and a distance from left:

```
ul li:nth-child(2) { /* second item */
    position:relative;
    left:5px;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) { /* third item */
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) { /* fourth item */
    position:relative;
    left:15px;
}
```

And so on...

Comment: Relative positioning will only work for the second list-item. The next ones should be translated by 40, 60, 80px, etc relative to the first one but will only moved by 20px. It doesn't add up, in short. EDIT: as the first one is also matched, it won't work at all I believe

Comment: It could be a tag cloud, there's no real limit to the number of items so I don't see the point of relative positioning here. Using padding (first part of your answer) is perfectly fine though

Comment: @FelipeAls OP asked for a way to "increase this space BETWEEN list items" without using margins. As far as i know, these are the only two methods.

Comment: The second method only works if there's a limit to the number of items (and if you know for sure what this limit is). I've already seen nav menus with 10 items horizontally and there are many other uses. padding does work, relative positioning *may* work

Comment: @FelipeAls yes you're absolutely right :) but that would be another question: how can i increase space between an undefined list of items

Answer (score 0):

Method #1: 
you can increase the margin-left property, starting from the 2nd LI: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw4LZ/

Method #2:
change the UL's word-spacing/letter-spacing to an higher value, and then set it back to "normal" for the LI elements: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw4LZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
font-size: 5em;
```

It will increase the space between inline-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the space between two list items you can easily do it in CSS

```
li
  {
    margin-top : 2px;
  }
```

You can change the value to suit the amount of space between the lists you want.